# How to change the width dynamically in JQuery datatables V1.9.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Width is coming dynamically in datatables even if give the inline width too.

Can I control the dynamic width with inline width

Answer (score 1):

You could add `!important` to your inline styles, but you should only need to apply it to the `th` elements and then every `<td>` in the same column should inherit that width.

e.g.

```
<tr>
  <th style="width: 100% !important;">Heading</th>
</tr>
```

You should also be able to turn it off using the correct initialisation option:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "autoWidth": false
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth